# Storyboard visual inheritance

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview, uistoryboard

On my main storyboard, I have 4 tabs on a tab controller: Favorites, Trending, Search, Browse.

All 4 tabs present data to the user on a Collection View.  How can I avoid having to design the same collection view cell 4 times, one time for each view controller of each tab?  Is there such thing as visual inheritance in Xcode/Swift?

Comment: It's hard to say for sure without seeing any code, but can't you just put the shared layout in its own xib, and then have each of the four controllers load the same xib?

Comment: composition. Create a separate controller with the collection view and put it inside your four controllers using container views.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to define the cells in the storyboard. If you want to reuse them use a nib file for the class rather than a storyboard.